# Please explain reasoning behind code snippet from argparse module

Tags: python, argparse

I was looking at the source code for the built-in [argparse._AppendAction](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action), which implements the `"append"` action, and puzzled over the [way it is implemented](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1f66fc397c8d/Lib/argparse.py#l946):

```
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = _copy.copy(_ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, []))
        items.append(values)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)
```

To break it down:

- `_ensure_value` is like `dict.setdefault` for attributes. That is, if `namespace` has an attribute with the name `self.dest` then it is returned, if not it is set to `[]` and returned.
- `_copy.copy(x)` returns just a shallow copy. When `x` is a list it is exactly like `list(x)` (but slower).
- Then the item is appended to the *copy* of the list gotten from `namespace`.
- Finally the `self.dest` attribute of `namespace` is overwritten with the copy, which should cause the old list to be garbage collected.

Why do it in such a roundabout and inefficient way, throwing away a whole list for each append? Why doesn't this suffice?

```
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = _ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, [])
        items.append(values)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an expert in the implementation, so (*disclaimer*) this is really just a guess.  With this implementation, the user can pass a list as a `default=...` in a call to `add_argument` without it being mutated within argparse.  Perhaps this type of safety was desired by the developers for one reason or another.

The inefficiency you mention really isn't a big deal.  It's for parsing commandline arguments, so this function is likely only called 10's of times per program under heavy usage.

---

I've tested this and indeed, If I use the following script (where `argparse_temp` is simply `argparse.py` copied to the current directory so I can play with it):

```
import argparse_temp as argparse

lst = [1,2,3]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l',default=lst,action='append')
print parser.parse_args()
print lst
```

This prints (when called as:  `python test1.py -l 4`):

```
Namespace(l=[1, 2, 3, '4'])
[1, 2, 3]
```

with `argparse` as is, but:

```
Namespace(l=[1, 2, 3, '4'])
[1, 2, 3, '4']
```

with your proposed change.

If you print the action that is returned by `add_argument`, you get:

```
_AppendAction(option_strings=['-l'], dest='l', nargs=None, const=None, default=[1, 2, 3, '4'], type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

Which is it conceivable that argparse depends on that action elsewhere in the implementation.  (Notice that `default` has been mutated here as well).

Comment: This sounds like the right answer. I guess it should be possible to avoid modifying the default argument while also improving efficiency, but I can't think of an elegant way of doing it, and as you say, this shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Comment: @lazyr -- And as a side note, `copy.copy` is used instead of slicing, probably so that the user isn't forced to pass a list.  Anything with an `append` method would work.